# How can we call the UI discussion pattern on Google+ or Facebook? Is it a chat?

Tags: social-interfaces

Look at this screenshot of a typical interaction on Google+:

[image]

How can we call it?

- Is it a chat?
- Is it a blogpost with comments?
- Is it a Q&A?

What's the proper name?

Answer (score 3):

I'd call it a **post with comments**, or with a **comment-thread**.